kernel tracing folder missed in ubuntu 22
/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/ or /sys/kernel/tracing/ is missing from UBUNTU 22 AWS instance.
We have rebooted to a different kernel and the tracing folder is missing suddenly due to some human error. Could you please suggest how to get this folder, or even how to rebuild this folder?
OS details:
Kernel :6.5.0-1023-aws,
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS" 
NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION_ID="22.04" 
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)" 
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy 
ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="ubuntu.com" SUPPORT_URL="help.ubuntu.com" BUG_REPORT_URL="bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=jamm

Thanks

Instead of posting a duplicate, please "bump" your previous question by editing in the information requested in the comments
